# Program freezes when saving images in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, save-image

I have created a winform program in visual studio 2012 that saves a image loaded into a picture box when another button is clicked. I first get the file path from the user with:

```
PrePath = {FileSave.Text,"RawData",Welcome.File(nextimagecounter)}
Path = IO.**Path**.Combine(PrePath)
Imagea.BackgroundImage.Save(Path)
```

Where `PrePath` is a String Array, `Path` is a string, `FileSave.Text` is user input in a txt box, `Welcome.File(nextimagecounter)` is a string that was stored in array File (found using `.GetFiles`) `Path = IO.Path.combine(PrePath)`, `Imagea.Backgroundimage` is the background image I want to save.

When I do this my program will freeze and I need to go to the task manager to end it. It also throw this error

```
An unhandled exception of type
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in
System.Drawing.dll
```

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Please note I also tried doing the call by:

```
Imagea.Background.Save(FileSave.Text+"\RawData\"+Welcome.File(nextimagecounter)+".jpg")
```

This did not work either, another post lead me to `Path.Combine`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "image loaded into a `image box`" do you actually mean a `PictureBox` control?

Comment: Yes, I will make that edit, thank you.